# Creating a list from an existing dataframe based on dplyr functions

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

I currently have a datatframe similar to this one:

```
df <- tibble("Fam_Name" = c("Architecture", "Arts", "Business", "Managers", "Medicine", "Science"), "Code" = c(1,1,2, 2,3, 3), "Share_2002" = c(0.116, 3.442, 2.445, 1.932, 0.985, 0.321), "Share_2018" = c(0.161, 0.232, 1.234, 0.456, 0.089, 0.06))
```

I would like to create a list called `family` which contains three other lists: `fam1, fam2, fam3`

Each `fam(i)` list would contain two dataframes called `fam_normal` and `fam_long` which are constructed based on dplyr functions, for instance:

```
fam_normal <- df %>% # I am not sure how to write this so that it is incorporated into the fam(i) list
              filter(Code == i) %>%
              rename("2002" = Share_2002,
                     "2018" = Share_2018)

fam_long <- fam_normal %>%
              gather(Year, Share, 3:4) %>%
              arrange(Fam_Name)
```

The end goal is to plot a graph for each `fam(i)` in the `fam` list where there are Years on the x-axis and Shares on the y-axis.

My real dataset has 25 families and more years.

Comment: Nice first question! Clear and reproducible, well done.

Comment: By the way, you can use `rename_at(starts_with("Share_"), ~ gsub("Share_", "", .))` to batch rename all your `Share_XXX` to `XXX`. Might be useful if you have a lot of years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first `rename` the columns use `group_split` to split them based on `Code` and then use `map` to get list of dataframes.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rename("2002" = Share_2002,
         "2018" = Share_2018) %>%
  group_split(Code) %>%
  map(~list(fam_normal = .x, fam_long = .x %>%
                                         gather(Year, Share, 3:4) %>%
                                         arrange(Fam_Name)))


#[[1]]
#[[1]]$fam_normal
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  Fam_Name      Code `2002` `2018`
#  <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 Architecture     1  0.116  0.161
#2 Arts             1  3.44   0.232

#[[1]]$fam_long
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  Fam_Name      Code Year  Share
#  <chr>        <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#1 Architecture     1 2002  0.116
#2 Architecture     1 2018  0.161
#3 Arts             1 2002  3.44 
#4 Arts             1 2018  0.232
#....
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution,

```
dd <- cbind.data.frame(df[1:2], stack(df[-c(1, 2)]))
Map(list, split(df, df$Code), split(dd, dd$Code))
```

which gives,

> ```
> $`1`
> $`1`[[1]]
> # A tibble: 2 x 4
>   Fam_Name      Code Share_2002 Share_2018
>   <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
> 1 Architecture     1      0.116      0.161
> 2 Arts             1      3.44       0.232
>
> $`1`[[2]]
>       Fam_Name Code values        ind
> 1 Architecture    1  0.116 Share_2002
> 2         Arts    1  3.442 Share_2002
> 7 Architecture    1  0.161 Share_2018
> 8         Arts    1  0.232 Share_2018
>
> ....
> ```

**NOTE:** You can change column names as per usual

Answer (score 2):

first you can work with the `purrr` package to work with nested tibbles:
this allows you define the sublists together:

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Code) %>%
  nest(.key = fam_normal) %>%
  mutate(fam_long = map(fam_normal, ~gather(.x, Year, Share, -Fam_Name) %>% 
                          arrange(Fam_Name) %>%
                          mutate(Year = parse_number(Year)))) %>%
  unnest(fam_long)
```

Then you can use `ggplot2` to get the plots:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x = Year, y = Share, color = Fam_Name)) + 
  geom_line(size = 2) + 
  facet_grid(Code~ .)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
fam <- list()

fam$normal <- df %>% 
              filter(Code == i) %>%
              rename("2002" = Share_2002,
                     "2018" = Share_2018)

fam$long <- fam$normal %>%
              gather(Year, Share, 3:4) %>%
              arrange(Fam_Name)
```

Now you have a named list `fam` containing your DFs. Your DFs are so custom that a `dplyr`solution may not be as legible as this simple assignment. I am a big fan of tidyverse-style coding but not when it gets in the way of clarity and legibility.

If you want to use this in a pipe, just create a function:

```
make_families <- function(df) {
 # insert code above
 # Return `fam`
 fam
}`
```

Then you're done: this will create the list of lists you describe.

```r
df %>%
  split(Fam_Name) %>%
  purrr::map(make_families)
```